# Twitter client, in reply to id

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, twitter

```
id = *********;
"in_reply_to_screen_name"= stackoverflow
```

Above you can see two examples of information I receive from the twitter API. I need to know how to get the value id.

To get `in_reply_to_screen_name` I use

```
-(NSString*)profileName {

return [contents objectForKey:@"in_reply_to_screen_name"];
}
```

How would I do this for id? The only difference is the `profileName` is in `" "` where the id isn't.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends in my experience whether you're getting the data as JSON or XML but generally the number will end up decoded as an NSNumber so I use:

`return [[contents objectForKey:@"in_reply_to_id"] unsignedLongLongValue];`

Comment: It is XML, I'll give that a go tomorrow. Not on the computer today. Thanks for the reply

Comment: "return makes pointer from integer without cast"    This is the error i'm getting now